# How to check if it is the first time or last time a macro has been used in ConTeXt?

Tags: macros, conditionals, context, context-mkiv

I have some text in my document which appears repeatedly many times throughout the document, so I have defined a custom macro, e.g.:

```
\define\mymacro{
    \section{A}
        There is some text.
    \section{B}
        This is some more text.
    \section{C}
        This is yet some more text.
}
```

This appears like this:

```
 _______________________
|                       |
| 1.1 A                 |
|    This is some text. |
| 1.2 B                 |
|    This is some more  |
|    text.              |
| 1.3 C                 |
|    This is yet some   |
|    more text.         |
|_______________________|
```

I need the macro to render differently in two situations.

- The first time the macro appears in the document, the title and contents of section A should not appear. Instead, alternative text apears.
- The last time the macro appears in the document, the title and contents of section C should not appaer. Instead, nothing appears there.

How can I create a conditional which checks if it is the first or last time the macro has been used, and modifies the text displayed accordingly?

Comment: I don't know if [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59272/14100) solution is relevant to ConTeXt but for the first occurrence maybe a similar technique could be used?  For the last occurence, could you increment a counter at each call, store the value of the counter somewhere (as in your question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34789/14100)) and have within your macro a check and branch for the final count?  That might be a naive suggestion, I'm not familiar with ConTeXt.

Comment: By the way, here are four of your own recent questions: [How to display the final value of a counter at the beginning of a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34789/2229); [How to retrieve a value which is set later on in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55365/2229);
[What documentation thoroughly explains TeX conditionals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53249/2229); and [How to check if a value is not equal using TeX conditionals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54576/2229). Did you try at all to use those to work out an answer?

Comment: Yes, I spent several hours attempting a solution, before posting, but had very limited success. Is it possible that the code for ConTeXt macros related to counters has been changed quite a bit from release to release? I have had very poor luck getting them to work with various versions of ConTeXt, hense many questions related to them.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I know ConTeXt used to use a set of commands ending in 'number': `\getnumber`, `\incrementnumber`, and [the like](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Counters); `\setpagenumber` & co. were part of that same system. Nowadays ConTeXt uses a more LuaTeX-integrated system with `\incrementcounter` and the like, and the 'number' commands have been redefined as synonyms for the 'counter' system. Then there are the [enumerations](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Category:Command/Numbered_objects), which use one of the two? That's all I know; but I don't know what changed when, or what MkII uses/d.

Comment: My best advice for you, since you use MkIV: go skim through [strc-num.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/strc-num.mkiv), and that should give you a good impression of which user-facing commands are available to you. The counter system and its commands haven't been documented on the wiki yet; I hope to get around to that soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counters are useful things. Here, I access them mainly from the Lua side, using `structures.counters.value` for value access, `structures.counters.add` for incrementing, and `structures.counters.last` to obtain the highest value attained occurs in the document. From the TeX side, I would have used `\rawcounter`, `\incrementcounter`, and `\lastcounter`. For more on the counter API, see http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Counters, and read [strc-num.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/strc-num.mkiv) and  [strc-num.lua](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/strc-num.lua).

```
\definecounter[mystuff]

\startluacode
    userdata = userdata or { }
    function userdata.domystuff() 
        -- * We must increment before, not after, or else the last value
        --   of the counter will always be one more than the value at last
        --   printing
        -- * I don't know why all these functions need a 1 as their second argument.
        structures.counters.add("mystuff", 1, 1)
        counter_val = structures.counters.value("mystuff", 1)
        if counter_val == 1 then
            context.section("A")
            context("We are at counter %s, the first counter.", counter_val)
        else
            context.section("A")
            tex.sprint("We are at counter \\rawcountervalue[mystuff]")
        end

        context.section("B")
        tex.sprint("section B's text")

        if not (counter_val == structures.counters.last("mystuff", 1)) then
            context.section("C")
            context("Last", counter_val)
        else
            context.par() -- start a new paragraph
            context("(Last section omitted)")
        end
        context.hairline()
    end
\stopluacode

% Define a TeX command to call the Lua function
\def\domystuff{\ctxlua{userdata.domystuff()}}

% Let's try it out
\starttext
    \startcolumns[n=2]
        \dorecurse{3}{
            \domystuff
        }
    \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

Thanks to Aditya's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55279/2229), and to Scott H. for his comment pointing at it.